# Why do Swami Ayyappa images have Namam symbol on the forehead?

Tags: customs, tilak, ayyappa

Why do swami Ayyappa images seem to have Namam symbol on the forehead? Is there any story behind that? He is the son for both Hari and Hara so shouldn't pattai be applied to swamy's forehead?

Comment: Sometimes he's depicted with a Vaishnava Namam, other times with the Shaivite symbol.  By the way, if he has a particular symbol on his forehead, it could just be that the kings of Pandalam were Vaishnavites or Shaivites at the time, so Manikandan as a prince of Pandalam wore the appropriate symbol on his forehead.

Comment: Every body saying that ayyapp is brothers to lord ganesh. So he must be a shaiva. Am i right?

Comment: Well, Ayyappa is a human incarnation of Dharma Shasta, son of Shiva and Mohini.  So his human parents might have been Vaishnavas.

Comment: mm.Great. But it seems assumption.There is no proofs. Anyway i believe myths.

Comment: Ayyappan is a vaishnavite who belongs to koli-shakya ( aryan )kshatriya, the descendant of suryavamsi. He was referred as "vellalakula jathan".Vellalar is one of the sub castes of Tamil Muthuraja community who are the descendants of koli-shakya kshatriyas.